# Load string to LINQ classes and query it

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I don't know too much about this subject yet, so I'm open to any suggestions that lead to my end goal...

1. I receive an XML string from a web service
2. I would like to load the string into a C# class capable of being used for LINQ
3. I would like to be able to extract an array of all "someentity" instances in the XML using LINQ with that class.

Here's some sample XML I made up with the someentity example:

```
<replydata>
    <someentity>
        <role id="1234" roletype="2" />
        <history length="24" accessstr="http://someurl" />
    </someentity>
    <someentity>
        <role id="1235" roletype="2" />
        <history length="30" accessstr="http://someurl2" />
    </someentity>
    ... keep repeating for a while
</replydata>
```

Is this possible, and if so, can someone provide a simple example or direct me to the right place to find one?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document

You should be able to de-serialize into a multi-dimensional object graph - and then go nuts!

Comment: That answer makes me want to cry for so many reasons :p.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var responseString =
    @"<replydata>
        <someentity>
            <role id=""1234"" roletype=""2"" />
            <history length=""24"" accessstr=""http://someurl"" />
        </someentity>
        <someentity>
            <role id=""1235"" roletype=""2"" />
            <history length=""30"" accessstr=""http://someurl2"" />
        </someentity>
    </replydata>";
var response = XElement.Load(new StringReader(responseString));
var someentitys = response.Elements("someentity");
foreach(var e in someentitys) {
    Console.WriteLine(
        "Role: {0}, access: {1}"
    ,   e.Element("role").Attribute("roletype")
    ,   e.Element("history").Attribute("accessstr")
    );
}
```

Comment: @downvoter I'm curious what do you think is wrong with this code: it runs perfectly fine, printing the expected lines. What gives?..

Comment: Works with a copy paste, you're a legend ;) LINQ is amazingly confusing at first glance, haha.

Answer (score 1):

The class you're looking for here is `XDocument`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx

You can create an `XDocument` from an XML String using it's `Parse()` method and then use LINQ to query that document.

Here's an article that demos its LINQ Capabilities

http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/10/understanding-c-simple-linq-to.html